# javascript - string replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

Given only the email address, I'm trying to remove the email, corresponding person's name and the following comma (if exist) from the string regardless where in the string the email appears.

```
var str = 'Peter Johnson <aa156@ss.edu>, Bob Cooper-Junior <aa1233@ss.edu>, John Michaels <qq@zzz.edu>';
```

so if I want to remove `'aa1233@ss.edu'` I would end-up with:

```
var str = 'Peter Johnson <aa156@ss.edu>, John Michaels <qq@zzz.edu>';
```

Thanks

Comment: Missing a necessary tag: javascript I presume? -- EDIT: Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not split the string using ',' as your delimiter and find which index contains 'aa1233@ss.edu' and rebuild the string without that index?  [See Working Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/E8bha/)

```
var newString = '';
var oldString = 'Peter Johnson <aa156@ss.edu>, Bob Cooper-Junior <aa1233@ss.edu>, John Michaels <qq@zzz.edu>';
var arrEmails = oldString.split(",");

for (i=0;i<arrEmails.length;i++){
    if (arrEmails[i].indexOf('aa1233@ss.edu') == -1){
        if (newString.length > 0) newString += ',' + arrEmails[i];
        else newString = arrEmails[i];
    }
}

alert(newString);
```

Comment: Agreed, I'd use `.join(',')` though... and `!~indexOf` perhaps

Comment: Until you have `Smith, John <j.smith@foo.bar>` in your contact list.

Comment: @Brad: Of course. I was basing my answer on the example he provided. I can't code for every possible case if I don't know every possible case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var toRemove = "aa1233@ss.edu";
   var str = 'Peter Johnson <aa156@ss.edu>, Bob Cooper-Junior <aa1233@ss.edu>, John Michaels <qq@zzz.edu>';
   var arr = str.split(",");
   for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].indexOf(toRemove) != -1) {
         str = str.replace(arr[i] + ",", "");
         break;
      }
   }

   // output it
   alert(str);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Peter Johnson <aa156@ss.edu>, John Michaels <qq@zzz.edu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[^,]+? <aa1233@ss.edu>,?
```

This will do what you want, tailor it to your precise needs.

[See here for more information.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

More than often, not using regular expressions is the cleaner solution:

```
var people = str.split(", ");

for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (people[i].indexOf(email) != -1) {
        people.splice(i, 1);
        str = people.join(", ");
        break;
    }
}
```